# Get IIS default installation directory

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7

From what I can tell all ASP.NET web applications are placed into `C:\inetpub` folder by default. But is there any way to retrieve this folder in a C# code? Or do I just hard code it?

PS. I need this as a default folder for my C# program that installs my web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is limited to my experience so . . . YMMV

I do not believe that there is a true default location.
IIS will host a site in any folder that IIS has access permissions for.  To determine what folder that might be, you can query the existing site list.

---

**BUT**

All is not lost.  You can figure out where those sites are!

In a new IIS installation you can locate the directory of the "Default Site" created during the IIS installation.

*Just keep in mind that there are no guarentees that the site will remain there.  Personally, I delete the Default Site as soon as I start to configure IIS.*

---

**In IIS 7+**

Site locations can be found in an XML file under IIS's configuration folder.

%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\

In the XML file applicationHost.config see

The XML Node path is:
/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/

From there you can iterate through each child node to see the various folder locations.  For example, the default site will probably be listed as:

```
child node:  site name="Default Web Site" id="1"
```

---

The .Net Way

Another trick would be to query IIS directly via .Net.

[Here is the API documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration)

Here are some methods to keep in your back pocket:

```
    private static Site GetSite(string siteName)
    {
        Site site = (from s in (new ServerManager().Sites) where s.Name == siteName select s).FirstOrDefault();

        if (site == null)
            throw new Exception("The Web Site Name \"" + siteName + "\" could not be found in IIS!");

        return site;
    }

    private static ApplicationCollection GetApplications(Site site)
    {
        //HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn("Site ID3: " + site + "/n");

        ApplicationCollection appColl = site.Applications;

        return appColl;
    }

    private static String GetHostName(Site site)
    {
        BindingCollection bindings = site.Bindings;

        String bind = null;

        foreach (Binding binding in bindings)
            if (binding.Host != null)
                return binding.ToString();

        return bind;
    }
```

---

**Update!**
While I can't guarantee that this location will remain after install, you can also [query the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx):

Check out HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp\pathWWWRoot\

---

Comment: check out my update at the bottom, its actually not so bad.  As long as that directory remains in place you're golden (just do some sanity checks before trying to write to it.)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the registry key. Although it should've been `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\INetStp\PathWWWRoot`

Comment: @ahmd0  No idea which OS I got that key from. I found it via a reg search on one of my boxes, but it could have been win 7 or 2008 R2.  Which OS are you running (might be helpful should other need the same info)?  PS: Thx for the followup!

Comment: It should work on any OS. Your `Wow6432Node` is present only when a 32-bit process (like Regedit for instance) is running on a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a seperate answer as its a completely different solution:

Do not worry where other apps are installed!

1. Use [Web Deploy](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx) (and if you're getting creative with Web Publish, you can even [set specific folder permissions](http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/SettingFolderPermissionsOnWebPublish.aspx))
2. If you need to do this pragmatically/have no access to those nifty tools...
   Choose a location and set permissions on the folder to ensure that IIS is able to access it.
   Then using the [IIS API's](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration) register your new site.
   Oh and you'll need to check those [app pool permissions](http://www.bluevalleytech.com/techtalk/blog/assigning-ntfs-folder-permission-to-iis7-application-pools/) too